# How can I develop a app using flutter with integrating a PDFs ? Pls someone help me with the roadmap

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basically, I'm trying to develop the app with simple UI and the with multiple integrations of PDFs simply to make like books, I'm fed up with the disorganized pdfs so I want to make it integrated to the app in itself so that it will be easier for me to see the pdfs when required.

I searched for the proper resources over the webs  I couldn't find any specific pathway for that so anyone seeing this can answer the question and help me out.

I'm really new to the Dart programming!

Comment: a creative way of describing a Homework project, if you can't find flutter and PDF's then it probably can't otherwise somebody would have written a small example or it would be in the flutter doc

Answer (score 0):

you can use combination of `path_provider` and `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer` packages.

`path_provider` will get you list of files in a directory and `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer` will view it.

this links will help you.

> [how to get a list of files from the directory and pass it to the ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521274/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-from-the-directory-and-pass-it-to-the-listview)
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider